# Conditioning multivariate Gaussian on a function of coordinates

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, statistical-inference, machine-learning

I have a pretty general question and I would really appreciate if you give me any hints or point me towards some relevant literature.

Suppose $X$ is an $n$-dimensional Gaussian vector.

What is the conditional distribution $\left[X|f(X)\right]$, where $f(X)$ is a non-linear function of the coordinates of $X$?
Are there any results/methods that deal with that kind of problems?

Thank you!